# Get SQL where value

Tags: mysql, sql, return, where-clause

I want to get the value of the where statement in a query.

For example:

```
UPDATE tablename SET name = 'test' WHERE lastname = 'doo'
```

I want query to return me `'doo'`. Is there any sql solution for it ?

Comment: You question doesn't make sense.  Do you want the `update` to return a value?  `Update` doesn't generally work like that.

Comment: Like SQL Server `UPDATE tablename  SET ... OUTPUT ... WHERE... `?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you really need this, but you have to use `SELECT` instead of `UPDATE` if you want to select any values, in following:

```
SELECT lastname
FROM tablename
WHERE name = 'test'
```

In this case you will select `lastname` where `name` is `'test'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT` query with `UPDATE` query for that :

```
UPDATE tablename SET name = 'test' WHERE lastname = 'doo';select lastname from tablename where lastname = 'doo';
```

Above query will return `lastname`.

I don't know about other DataBase but for `MS SQL Server` you can use directly like this(may be it's not good but will work)

```
UPDATE tablename SET name = 'test' WHERE lastname = 'doo';select 'doo' as lastname;
```

it will result the same as first query.